# Как преобразовать System String в string?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте.

Как преобразовать **System String в string или в fstream**? Идея какая. Открываете опен файл диалогом файл на чтение... И всё то, что открылось помещаете в fstream.
Проблема с помещением в fstream.

```
fstream myStream;   
string str;

if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
{
    System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
    MessageBox::Show(sr->ReadLine());
    myStream=sr;
    sr->Close();
}
```

Comment: Что то вроде 
переменная = convert переменная to string

Comment: Пробовал, может на примере покажете?

Comment: Зачем смешивать файловые потоки C++ и потоки .NET? Это совсем разные типы, которые не должны быть совместимы. Используй либо fstream, либо StreamReader.

Comment: А как использовать StreamReader? Он сильно отличается от 1-го....
В него не запишешь так вот myStream>>"прап";
Проблема в том, что я не пойму как работать с этим StreamReader? а поэтому хочу перевести его в fstream... Или в чего угодно...

Comment: В потоках `std` смешаны понятия бинарного и текстовых потоков, а также читателей/писателей. В .NET класс Stream это бинарный поток, допускающий чтение/запись байтов, а для чтения/записи текста и любого другого содержимого используются ридеры/райтеры, например, TextReader, XmlReader (и соответствующие райтеры).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование System::String ^ в std::string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775727/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-systemstring-%d0%b2-stdstring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string SystemToStl(String ^s)
    {
        using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
        const char* ptr = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
        return string(ptr);
    }
```

Comment: Хмм... А не возникнет ли проблемы, связанной с освобождением памяти? Строку выделенную с помощью [`Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx) разве не нужно освобождать с помощью `Marshal::FreeHGlobal()` (как указано на странице документации)?