# Преобразование System::String ^ в std::string

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli

```
std::string abc = this->login_textbox->Text;
```

Ошибка:
*E0415  не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "System::String ^" в "std::basic_string, std::allocator>"*

Comment: В проекте WinForms не используйте `std::string`. Используйте `System::String`.

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то имеет смысл работать с управляемыми строками, как [в ответе Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775738/10105), раз уж ваш проект на C++/CLI. Но если очень сильно хочется, можно смаршаллировать (небесплатно):

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
```

```
std::wstring abc = marshal_as<std::wstring>(this->login_textbox->Text);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System::String ^abc = this->login_textbox->Text;
```

Comment: а если мне в классе нужно?