# Как использовать функцию возврата string в c++ windows forms?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

В Windows Forms я использую два объекта textBox. Информация из первого должна стать одним из параметров для второго textBox.
Соответственно, значение textBox1 присваивается переменной text типа данных String^. Но дальше я не могу передать эту переменную в качестве аргумента в функцию, которая принимает string.
Как исправить?

```
if (checkBox1->Checked) {
        text = System::Convert::ToString(textBox1->Text);
        key = System::Convert::ToString(textBox3->Text);
        textBox2->Text = (encrypte(text, key));
}
```

Так тоже не работает:

```
textBox2->Text = System::Convert::ToString(encrypte(text, key));
```

Comment: Никак! Забудьте про C++/CLI. Этот язык не используется для написания полноценных приложений. Он используется только в качестве _клея_ между управляемым (managed) и неуправляемым/нативным (unmanaged/native) кодом. Если хотите использовать WinForms - пишите на C# - жизнь станет легка и приятна. Если хотите выучить C++ (настоящий, без CLI), то забудьте про WinForms и снесите нахер Visual Studio. Эта IDE прекрасна, но к вашей беде позволяет совмещать код на C++ и C++/CLI, поэтому вы так и будете путаться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov это моя практическая работа, но спасибо

Comment: Передайте вашему преподавателю от моего имени, что он мудак! Я это годами пишу постоянно всем несчастным школярам, которых заставляют учить C++/CLI. Пока ещё ни разу ни один рассерженный препод не приходил ко мне с обидами. То есть вы все ссыте даже анонимно послать преподам ссылку на мой коммент.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не преподаватели ведь учебную программу пишут

Comment: Этот вопрос регулярно задаётся. Ответ на него давался много раз. Элементарно ищется поиском. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775727/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю. уже пробовала. выскакивает
Ошибка C4996 'msclr::interop::error_reporting_helper<_To_Type,_From_Type,false>::marshal_as': \

Comment: Не пишите в комментариях, редактируйте вопрос.